# Play framework, Different constraints for different requests

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

How to implement different constraints for different requests? For example, there is `User` class:

```
public class User extends Model{
  @Required
  @Email
  @Id
  public String email;

  @Required
  @Column(length = 50)
  public String firstname;

  @Required
  @Column(length = 50)
  public String lastname;

  @Required
  public String password;
}
```

When I create a new user, all constraints are required. But when I update user information, I don't need the password constraint.

Should I create separate classes for `createUser()` and `updateUser()` actions?
Is there any way I can use just one class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Play's validation framework conforms to the Java bean validation specification (JSR-303), you can use the validation groups feature that is part of the spec. This is exactly what you are looking for - a neat way of enforcing different validation rules for different actions. You can see an example of how to use it in code in [this answer I gave to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22460679/926710).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can one property have multiple groups? For example, groups ={A.class, B.classs}, like this

Comment: @DavaahuuJamsran - Yes. The syntax is ``@Required(groups={ Create.class, Update.class })``.

Comment: I am play framework 2.2.4 and it is not working. Even one group is not working( @Required(groups=Create.claass)). Any ideas?

Comment: @DavaahuuJamsran You need to make changes to your model and controller classes. Have another look at the link from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practise to mix "back-end entity" annotations with "front-end entity" annotations. Create separate class for inserting user and updating user with @Required annotations accordingly. Remove front-end annotations from User entity and leave only JPA annotations like @Id @Column etc.

Comment: Whilst I agree with this answer and actually do what it says myself, it doesn't answer the OPs actual question (should it be a comment maybe). However I WOULD recommend this as the approach one should take.